# Добавление данных в конец Excel файла

Tags: c#, excel, update, table

Есть вот такая библиотека. `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`
Для работы с таблицами Excel. С записью в таблицу я разобрался а вот как добавить в существующую таблицу новую информацию в конец файла не понимаю.
Это мой код он рабочий но он перезаписывает существующий фаил. Подскажите как дописать в существующую таблицу данные в конец.

```
//создаём новое Excel приложение
Excel.Application exApp = new Excel.Application();
//добавляем рабочую книгу
exApp.Workbooks.Add();
//обращаемся к активному листу (по умолчанию он первый)
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)exApp.ActiveSheet;
//добавляем строку в Excel файл
workSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "4.1";
//Вместо чисел можно использовать буквенное обозначение.
workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "1.B";
workSheet.Cells[2, 4] = "1.3";
//Сохранение в Excel файл;
workSheet.SaveAs(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно найти последнюю строчку и сделать инкремент на 1:

```
int _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find(
                              "*",
                              xlWorkSheet.Cells[1,1],
                              Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                              Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                              Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                              Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
                              misValue,
                              misValue,
                              misValue
                              ).Row + 1;
```

Используя этот индекс, ты можешь обратится к новой строке и писать туда данные.

А вообще, лучше использовать либу EPPlus, так как interop тормозной.

Comment: Если не сложно не подскажешь где можно побольше про EPPlus почитать. Описание методов и тп. А ищу но пока ничего толкового не нашел.

Comment: @АртурОлеговичПлюх, ну вот тут несколько примеров есть http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.ru/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html . Либа достаточно интуитивно понятная.